# I want to iterate the Table using .childNodes, then find the <B> tag. My code doesn't work!

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in my code. I want to get the b tag that has the style color silver using Javascript. I tried using the tagName === "B" but it didn't work. I figured that the B tags are not children of the rowData class.

```
  <tr class="rowData">
    <td style="padding: 0pt;">
                <table><tr>
                <td>
                    <b style="font-size: 15px; color: silver;">Mugging</b>
                    <br />Payout: <b style="color: green;">$200 - $300</b>
                    <br />Experience: +1                                    </td>

                <td style="text-align: right;">
                                    </td>
            </tr></table>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0pt;">
            <table><tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <b style="color: gray;">Required:</b>

                    <br />Energy:&nbsp;1                                    </td>
                <td style="">
                                    </td>
            </tr></table>
        </td>

        </td>
  </tr>
```

I removed some part of it..

Here's some part of the Javascript code:

```
var jobs = {};

jobs.scan = function() {
    var tagHolder = {};
    var availJobs = {};
    var jobContents = dom.get("app8743457343_content");
    var rData = dom.getElementsByClass("rowData", jobContents, "tr");
    for(var i = 0; i < rData.length; i++) {
        var rChildren = rData[i].childNodes;
        for(var j=0; j<rChildren.length; j++) {
            if(rChildren[j].tagName === 'B') {
                alert(rChildren[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

jobs.scan();
```

When I started the script it didn't alert, or responded. Maybe I need to use something to like nextSibling? Please help me figure this out.. I want the b with the style color silver. The Mugging text

Comment: Could the code be modified to use spans with id's or classes instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* fight the good fight and try to get that monstrosity working across all browsers....

Or, you could try [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)! It's fun and easy, and all the cool kids are doing it!

```
var text = $('tr.rowData').find('b').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('color') == 'silver';
}).text();
alert(text);
```

Tada!

**EDIT**: In all seriousness, if you want to do it in raw javascript, this works for me on IE and Firefox:

```
var text;
var bs = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
for(var x = 0; x < bs.length; x++) {
    if(bs[x].style.color == 'silver') {
        text = bs[x].innerHTML;
        break;
    }
}
alert(text);
```

It is just grabbing all the bold elements in the document and checking to see which one has a color of silver. This is not *super* efficient, obviously, and I am not sure of your use case. I do see in your code you are first grabbing a reference to a `jobContents` element. I am not sure where that is coming from as you didn't post that part of the markup, but if the `<b>` will end up being inside this element, you can change this line:

```
var bs = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
```

To this:

```
var bs = jobContents.getElementsByTagName("b");
```

Which will then 1) speed it up, 2) make sure you get what you want.

Good luck.

Comment: ye, im actually using it sometimes. But i want to master the raw javascript first before I proceed to jQuery. Because I think that i'll become a better javascript programmer if i know the raw javascript.

Comment: @unknown: I agree somewhat with your statement, but often times what makes you a good programmer is knowing how to piece together the high-level abstractions in a way that yields useful results. You'll save time by not having to dredge through the miscellaneous details.

Comment: Hi.. Sorry for being so pushy.. I'm a very new programmer actually. I just started my comsci course. I'm passionate in programming. Actually it's already 3AM here, and I'm still coding. I need to wake up 7am to class. One of my bad behaviour is I tend to look in to details v. seriously.

Comment: I'll just finish this Greasemonkey script then, proceed to jQuery. It's kinda big script cause I'll automate all the aspects of the game. Then after that I'll proceed to jQuery. Then code my next personal project in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't go down deep enough into the tree.  You need at least 4 more levels of childNode "for" loops to get to the "B" tag.  If you go this route then you should probably make a recursive function that searches for your "B" tag.